# ansible to pick & iterate the location name from the file sequencly

Tags: ansible-2.x

I have written a playbook to install our custom collectd and that's working , where i'm changing the configuration with `lineinfile` module now i have another situation where i have multiple site names like one i have in my playbook ie `richmod`  as follows:

> Prefix "collectd.dns.NA.richmond.physical.

i have multiple site name viz richmond, carry, london, boston hence looking forward to put them into a varible and call that variable to assign the value.
lets suppose when it  run the playbook on first Server it should pick up "richmon" for second it should pick up carry, for third it should london and so on.. looking for ideas..

```
---
- name: Playbook to Install CollectD
  #hosts: all[1]
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Downloading collectd
    get_url:
      url="http://my-dc/collectd-5.7.2.tar.gz"
      dest="/opt/"

  - name:  Extracting collectd archive
    unarchive:
      src="/opt/collectd-5.7.2.tar.gz"
      dest="/opt/"
      remote_src=True

  - name:  Creating soft link to collectd Dir
    file:
      src: "/opt/collectd-5.7.2"
      dest: "/opt/collectd"
      state: link
      owner: root
      group: root
#############################################################################################
# Dont Disable the gather_facts at all as {{ ansible_hostname }} absolutlty depends on facts #
# ###########################################################################################

  - name: Committing changes to collectd configuration....
    lineinfile:
      dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
      regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
      line: "{{ item.line }}"
      backrefs: yes
    with_items:
      - { dest: '/opt/collectd/etc/collectd.conf', regexp: '#Hostname    "collectServer"', line: 'Hostname  "{{ ansible_hostname }}"' }
      - { dest: '/opt/collectd/etc/collectd.conf', regexp: '#    Prefix "collectd.unix."', line: '    Prefix "collectd.dns.NA.richmond.physical."' }

  - name: Copy the collectd Daemon to init ..
    copy:
      src: "/opt/collectd/startup/collectd"
      dest: "/etc/init.d/"
      remote_src: True
      mode: 0755
      owner: root
      group: root

  - name: starting collectd Service
    service:
      name: collectd
      state: started
      enabled: yes
```

Comment: You may want to read about host/group variables: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#host-variables

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov, thnx i'm reading through...